# How to detect what element has the focus, on touch devices

Tags: javascript, touch, selectors-api

To detect what element is fired, when my user clicks on an anchor or submits a form, I use that selector :

```
'form input[type=submit]:focus,' +
'form button[type=submit]:focus,' +
'form button:not([type]):focus,' +
'a:focus,' +
'form input[type=submit],' +
'form button[type=submit],' +
'form button:not([type])'
```

But it doesn't work on touch devices, how to solve it please ?

Comment: Look at the Event object?

Comment: @SLaks : I can't, because it doesn't works on form submit by an "Enter" on an input element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution: try to get the element by the pseudo-selector `:hover`, in place of `:focus`